# What is the Maxwell equation for a polarised light?

Tags: maxwell-equations, polarization

In the Dirac equation for a massless fermion, for example, in the Weyl representation, we can split the equation into two separate equations for left-handed and right-handed electrons. In the Weyl represenation, the spinor is split as $\psi=(\psi_L,\psi_R)$

For the Maxwell equation for a massless photon, can we split this into two equations, for each of the two polarizations of light? I'm not sure how one would split the 4-vector potential $A_\mu$ into the two polarization states e.g. $\phi_L$ and $\phi_R$.

Also, is there some operator analagous to the $\frac{1}{2}(1+\gamma^5)$ operator for the Dirac equation that gives us one of the two polarization states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The  [Riemann-Silberstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Silberstein_vector) form
of Maxwell's equations is precisely the analogue of the decomposition of Dirac into its left and right handed parts. See my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/429782/chirality-of-the-electromagnetic-field-tensor/429845#429845).